# How to display expandable cards inside a lazy column in Jetpack Compose [that shows a list when expanded]?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**I'm trying to add Expandable Card inside lazy Column but it's not working**

When the content is displayed I want Mechanics card to be out of screen as Lazy Column does as shown in the images below.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsCiq.jpg

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkAZV.jpg

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsMechanics)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsThermodynamics)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsSound)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsOptics)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsElectrostatics)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsElectricityAndMagnetism)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        ExpandableCard(subjects = PhysicsModernPhysics)
```

**Expandable Card:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ExpandableCard(subjects: Subjects, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var expandedState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val rotationState by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (expandedState) 180f else 0f, label = ""
    )

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 300,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        onClick = {
            expandedState = !expandedState
        }
    ) {
        // card content
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(12.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = subjects.name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium
            )

            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .rotate(rotationState),
                onClick = {
                    expandedState = !expandedState
                }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
        if (expandedState) {
            ChapterColumn(chapters = subjects.chapters)
        }
    }
}
```

**Chapter Column:**

```
@Composable
fun ChapterColumn(

    chapters: List<ChapterName>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(chapters) { item ->
            ChapterBox(chapterName = item)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        }
    }

}
```

**Chapter Box**

```
@Composable
fun ChapterBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    chapterName: ChapterName
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(color = Color(0xFF8F6F5FA), RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    )
    {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            Image(painter = painterResource(id = chapterName.icon), contentDescription = null)
            Column {
                Text(text = chapterName.name, maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
                Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))
                Text(
                    text = chapterName.description,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            }
        }

    }

}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently not able to test your code, and also, you haven't provided any description what exactly is not working or how your current application looks. But at the first glance, I noticed some things that might be problematic:

- In your `ChapterBox`, you are setting `modifier.fillMaxSize()`. At the same time, your Card does `wrapContentHeight()` by default. I would expect that a single `ChapterBox` will be pushing all other contents off screen as soon as you expand a Card.
- In your `ChapterColumn`, you are using a LazyColumn. A LazyColumn uses `fillMaxHeight()` by default.
- You probably want the list of your `ExpandableCards` to be scrollable too. You however can only have one vertically scrolling layout in each screen, if you don't apply a fixed height to the inner scrolling layout.

I think what you actually are aiming for is a **scrollable** LazyColumn that contains all the `ExandableCards`. Each `ChapterBox` then just has a **non-scrollable** Column that displays all subtopics. When you expand a Card, and the Column exceeds the screen, the top-level LazyColumn will allow you to scroll.

Wrap your top-level subjects inside of a scrollable LazyColumn:

```
@Composable
fun PhysicList(
    subjects: List<Subjects>,
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(subjects) { item ->
            ExpandableCard(subjects = item)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

Use a normal non-scrollable Column in your ChapterColumn:

```
@Composable
fun ChapterColumn(

    chapters: List<ChapterName>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.wrapContentHeight) {
        chapters.forEach { item ->
            ChapterBox(chapterName = item)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

Use wrapContentHeight() in your Box:

```
@Composable
fun ChapterBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    chapterName: ChapterName
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(color = Color(0xFF8F6F5FA), RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment is very insightful and I learnt a few things and fixed the problem.